# How to breakup Sitecore/Index Request in Application Insights

Tags: app-insight

So if your using Application Insights w/ your Sitecore setup, you've invariably seen the following when perusing the basic reporting. A lot of request going to the cryptic **Sitecore/Index**.

[image: Sitecore/Index as shown in Application Insights]

As you can imagine this is troubling, as I figured out, the **Sitecore/Index** is referred to as the *Page level controller* which underlying is an MVC Controller/Action  `SitecoreController.Index()`, which is called for every route that matches an item path, so alot.

> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14999263/2446435

It would be more helpful if I could instead log the Item Path or something. But this got me thinking, Why not log the Renderings. Let's refer to my illustration of a typical Sitecore page.

[image: a typical sitecore page]

So I was thinking about this in a similar way to how the Sitecore Debugger works. 
http://www.glass.lu/Blog/Archive/Using%20the%20Sitecore%20Debug%20Tool%20Part%201

If I could hijack the pipeline, I could call `TelemetryClient.TrackRequest()` or `TrackDependency()`. However, I don't really think this option is ideal.

First if I used a `Dependency` object, `Dependency` objects are relatively primitive. Rendering are more of a `Request`, Item Paths of their own, potentially `dependencies` of their own, etc etc, too much detail and complexity to be represented as a `dependency`. Unless I were to just track the new `Request` as a `Dependency` of the Old `Request`.

So yes, I could call `TrackRequest`, but I'm not really sure the Framework would attach all the inner `dependencies` of my Rendering correctly, they would most likely be tied to the OOTB `Request` Object.

Rather I would like to Hijack the Pipeline in Sitecore where Renderings Begin and Complete their execution. The way I see it is to try and leverage as much of the OOTB Rendering Object where Application Insights attaches more telemetry to the current `Operation_ID`, taking advantage of correlation.

But for example, I only want Telemetry executed within the confines of the `HeaderControllerRendering` associated with the corresponding `Request`. Maybe I allow the Telemetry inside this component to be associated with its corresponding `Request` object, as well as shared with its Ancestors `Request` objects (IE `Main_Layout.cshtml` and so on depending on how far your rendering hierarchy goes). 
But I certainly don't want, for example, Telemetry of `Top Main View Rendering.cshtml` or `Footer Controller Rendering` associated with the `Request` object of `HeaderControllerRendering` as they are in this scenario cousin renderings(?)

So If you are not keeping up with this, I understand, it's a little convoluted, let me try and explain it with some pseudo code.

> Note: I think I need something like PipelineBasedRequestFilter 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599581/2446435

```
public class MyHypotheticalRenderingFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        RequestTelemetry parentRequest = HttpContext.GetRequestTelemetry();
        RequestTelemetry request = new Request();
        request.ParentOperationID = parentRequest.OperationID;
        TelemetryRequestBag.SaveRequest(request); 
        parentRequest = request;
    }

    public virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        RequestTelemetry request = HttpContext.GetRequestTelemetry();
        TelemetryClient.TrackRequest(request);
        RequestTelemetry request = TelemetryRequestBag.RetreiveRequest(request.ParentOperationID);    
    }
}

public class TelemetryRequestBag
{
    private Dictionary<string, RequestTelemetry> requestTelemetry;

    public TelemetryRequestBag()
    {
        requestTelemetry = new Dictionary<string,RequestTelemetry>();
    }

    SaveRequest(RequestTelemetry request)
    {
        requestTelemetry.Add(request.OperationID, request);
    }

    RetrieveRequest(string Operation_ID)
    {
        return requestTelemetry.Get(Operation_ID);
    }
}
```

The goal here would be to go from something like this, where I have 43 results for a `Request` that starts with Sitecore/Index

[image]

To significantly less and including a row like this:

- **timestamp**: 2018-10-08T01:48:32.114
- **itemType**: request
- **operation_Id**: MYNewOperationIDHere
- **operation_Name**: ControllerRendering: Analytics/FullStory
- **operation_ParentId**: 40765245d3a270409a420f6735a09dc3

And If I ran the following Query, I'd expect back the preceding row, and any of the `dependencies`, `traces`, or subsequent `requests` that occur as a result of `MYNewOperationIDHere`.

```
union *
| where operation_Id == "MYNewOperationIDHere"
    or operation_ParentId == "MYNewOperationIDHere"
| project timestamp, itemType, operation_Id, operation_Name, operation_ParentId
```

- **timestamp**: 2018-10-08T01:48:32.114
- **itemType**: request
- **operation_Id**: MYNewOperationIDHere
- **operation_Name**: ControllerRendering: Analytics/FullStory
- **operation_ParentId**: 40765245d3a270409a420f6735a09dc3

**Questions**

1. Where in Sitecore can I hook into, to take similar action to do what I do in the pseudo code?
2. Can anyone point out any major flaws/possible bugs in my solution around the Application Insights Schema.
3. Can anyone point out any major flaws/possible bugs in my solution around Sitecore.

Comment: Very good question. Have you tried to just register your action filter as a global MVC filter? It will then be executed for your custom controllers and for sitecore controllers. There are also pipelines in sitecore like <mvc.actionexecuted> you can take a look at.

Answer (score 4):

While not the answer to breaking down logging each rendering, It's quite possible to change the `GET Sitecore/Index` to show its correct url.

You need to implement a custom telemetry processor, looking at the request item and updating both the `Name` properties of the request item as well as for the Operation. Operation Name is what you see Azure Portal.

Full blog post and code is available here: https://medium.com/@osbeck.per/geting-the-fix-for-sitecore-index-318bcfaaa690

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are misusing request object. While I agree,  renaming Sitecore/Index to URL will be helpful, to get details of execution of one request you should use profile traces.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-overview